# How to handle fcm when app in in background and play sound on notification arrival in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, background, playsound

I want to play a sound when a notification arrives, but I am not able to play. If the app is opened the sound is played and is working fine. But when the app is killed I see the notification but the sound is not played. 
Please help how to do it.

```
@override
```

void initState() 
{

```
super.initState();
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on message $message');
    String key = message["data"]["fcm_call_api"];
    if (key == "approval") {}
    if(Platform.isAndroid)``
    {
      _playSound();
    }

  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    _playSound();
  },
);
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
    const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
_firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
    .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {

});
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
  assert(token != null);
  setState(() {
    _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
  });

});
```

}

```
void _playSound() {
AudioCache player = new AudioCache();
const alarmAudioPath = "notification_tone.mp3";
player.play(alarmAudioPath);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify on which platform you experience this problem, but overall background messages with the firebase messaging plugin is very limited right now, but there is a PR actively fixing this: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1900 (related issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22072)

Right now it is documented behavior that messages arriving in the background are only delivered once it is brought back into foreground (on android). See it's documentation at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages:

[image: firebase messaging plugin documentation]